# Access Violation using ReadProcessMemory to get a string value

Tags: c++, winapi, reverse-engineering

I'm new to reverse engineering, and quite new to C++. I'm trying to collect a player's character name in a game using `ReadProcessMemory()` from the Win32 API, but it throws an exception whenever I try to read it:

```
if (procId != NULL) {
    hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procId);
    ModuleBase = getModuleBaseAddr(procId, "ac_client.exe");
    localPlayerptr = ModuleBase + 0x10f4f4;
    healthaddr = findDMAaddy(hprocess, localPlayerptr, { 0xf8 });
    //load to entitylist Array
    ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, (BYTE*)localPlayerptr, &Entitylist[0], sizeof(Entitylist[0]), 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, (BYTE*)ModuleBase + 0x10f4f8, &Entitylist[i], sizeof(Entitylist[i]), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(hprocess,(BYTE*) Entitylist[i]+(i*4), &Entitylist[i], sizeof(Entitylist[i]), 0);
        std::cout << std::hex << Entitylist[i] << std::endl;
        uintptr_t nameaddres;
        std::string name;
        nameaddres = Entitylist[i] + 0x225;
        //ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, (BYTE*)nameaddres, &name, sizeof(name), 0); 
        /*--> ** This is where I have a problem. ***/
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: You can't read memory into a `std::string` and expect it to work. You need a plain buffer (e.g. `wchar_t buf[100]`).

Comment: Aside from the complete lack of error handling, you are not allocating memory for the `std::string`'s char data for `ReadProcessMemory()` to read into. You can't read into a `std::string` directly, that will overwrite its internal data members. You need to read into the `std::string`'s char buffer, whose address is returned by the `std::string::data()` method, for instance. But first, you need to determine how many bytes to even read from the other process, you can't use `sizeof(std::string)` for that. This code is not trying to determine the target string's length before reading the string

Comment: Just an aside, you should only specify the access rights you actually require when calling  `OpenProcess`.  This will increase the chance of the call succeeding.  In this case, `PROCESS_VM_READ` should be sufficient.

Comment: wchar_t one work forme but idk how to convert them because they are collecting same result from each entity, and yes me using process all access for this one

Comment: use `std::wcout << name` to out put a `wchar_t*` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to determine whether the string you want to read is a wide-byte (wchar) or multi-byte (char) version, then you could use `std::string/char*` or `std::wstring/wchar_t*`.

Second, do not use `sizeof(std::string)`, you need to determine the length of the string you want to read.
For wide-byte:

`&(std::string)name` is not a writable address, as comments pointed out, you could use a wchat_t array instead:

```
wchat_t name[100];
BOOL ret = ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, (BYTE*)nameaddres, name, sizeof(name), 0);
```

Or you could use `&name[0]`(From @Remy):

```
std::wstring name;
name.reserve(100);
BOOL ret = ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, (BYTE*)nameaddres, &name[0], 100*sizeof(wchar_t), 0);
std::wcout << name << std::endl;
```

Then, `std::cout` is not available for the `wchar_t*`, it only prints the address value. It is a local variable in the for loop, so it will reallocate the address every time comes in. Due to certain rules, the system may prefer to choose the same address, so you've got the same address value.

Use the `std::wcout << name` to out put the wchar_t string, and If the output is always only one character, then you may consider using the multi-byte version to read memory.

Comment: "*In addition, `std::string::data()` now is also a `const char*` type, so it is not recommended to use to reveice the string*" - a non-const version of `data()` was added in C++17. In C++11..14, you can use `&name[0]` instead (and *usually*, this also works in earlier versions, too).

Comment: Thanks, and I have modified the answer.

Comment: you are not `resize()`'ing the `std::wstring` to allocate memory for the character data before reading into it

Comment: In the second example, why do you reserve 100 16 bit elements, but then read only 50 elements?